# how to transfer value to another page with link?

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: Example]

Hello i'm stil learning, using **Codeigniter** can someone tell me, or give example code?
what i need is in `Round Id` we have `111` i want give it link and search database with value 111 how to do that? here the code i tried but still not right

```
<div class="row" id="ajaxdata">
        <table border="1">  
            <tr>
                <th>Round Id</th>
                <th>Player Id</th>
                <th>Bet Place</th>
                <th>Total Bet</th>
                <th>Win</th>
                <th>Lose</th>
            </tr>

            <?php foreach ($tbl_bet_spot as $data) {?>  
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('account/detail_round_id?select=111');?>"><?php echo $data->round_id;?></a>
                    <td><?php echo $data->id;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data->bet;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data->total_bet;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data->win;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data->lose;?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </table>
        </table>
</div>
```

controller

```
public function detail_round_id(){
        $select = $_GET['select'];

        $data['tbl_bet_spot'] = $this->login_model->selectRoundId_by_round($select)->result();

        print_r ($data);
    }
```

i just try with my code and it work now, but it's static in here

```
<td><a href="<?php echo site_url('account/detail_round_id?select=111');?>"><?php echo $data->round_id;?></a>
```

how i can send this value `<?php echo $data->round_id;?>` properly into controller? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code

```
<td><a href="<?php echo site_url()?>/account/detail_round_id/<?php echo $data->round_id;?>"><?php echo $data->round_id;?></a></td>
```

controller

```
public function detail_round_id(){
        $select = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $data['tbl_bet_spot'] = $this->login_model->selectRoundId_by_round($select)->result();

        print_r ($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this may help you,

In view make link like this,

```
<td><a href="<?php echo site_url('account/detail_round_id/'.$data->round_id);?>"><?php echo $data->round_id;?></a>
```

And in controller add parameter like this,

```
public function detail_round_id($id){
    $data['tbl_bet_spot'] = $this->login_model->selectRoundId_by_round($id)->result();
    print_r ($data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

view page you pass value like this

```
  <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>account/detail_round_id/select/<?=$data->round_id?>"><?php echo $data->round_id;?></a>
```

In controller get value like this

```
 $select=$this->uri->segment(4);
```

hope this will help